# Overlap images in a stack or relative layout in xamarin forms

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, stacklayout

I have a list of images in an Assets folder in my PCL project, all these images are as embedded resource, and I can get these images and display normally in a ContentPage derived class without using xaml, but, I need to put those images overlapped to another as in the example below: 
[image]

How I position these images like in the image showed?
someone can help-me?
Iam completely noob in Xamarin Froms c#

thanks in advance!

Comment: You can archive that by using grid, when you put many elements on the same row or column they will overlap, just use grid with one row an add every image to the same row with left margin to get your desire effect. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid

PS: if the image will be only static you should put only one image with all them, try merge the images with Photoshop or something like that, because performance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned "without using XAML" I understand then that you are using C# (code behind) to load and present your images.

The easiest way to make some overlapping on the images is by making all your images children of a `StackLayout` and setting a negative spacing in the `StackLayout`.

[image]

```
private void LoadSomeImages()
{
    stackImages.Children.Clear();
    stackImages.Spacing = -25;
    stackImages.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        var image = new Image
        {
            WidthRequest = 60,
            HeightRequest = 59
        };

        image.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("SWOverlappedImages.reactivex.png");
        stackImages.Children.Add(image);
    }
}
```

Being

`stackImages` the `StackLayout` that will be holding the Images.

`reactivex.png` the image name in your resources.

The negative `Spacing` will tell how much overlapping you desire. Also, keep in mind that `Spacing` and the `Image` `Width` are highly related.

In the example above by setting the Spacing on -25, I am overlapping almost half of the Image.

Also, the above will work fine if all the images share the same size, or at least the same `Width`.

Comment: nice man! its wok fine! thanks!